# Does Windows 7 Starter really not support the .Net framework?

Tags: .net, windows-7

I stumbled across this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww.aspx

Is this strictly true? Does Windows 7 *Starter* Edition really not support the .Net framework?

Or...
- Can you get it installed anyway, but Microsoft doesn't support it.
- Are there older versions, e.g. 2.0 or 3.0 which will work?

Answer (score 2):

It definitely supports it.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww.aspx

It probably always did but the page used to have a typo or they just meant that the run-time wasn't installed by default.

Answer (score 1):

This seems so silly but does appear to be true.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions) (*2012.01.18 - currently the article does not mention .NET Framework*):

> Windows 7 Starter is the edition of Windows 7 that contains the fewest features. The Windows Aero theme is not included in this version, and it is not available in a 64-bit variant. The desktop wallpaper, and Visual Style (Windows 7 Basic) is also not user-changeable (however can be done using 3rd party software). It also doesn't support .NET Framework.[10]

=================

Based on the link below from Microsoft, Windows 7 starter DOES support .NET framework 4.0
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww.aspx

I think the wikipedia info is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, that's where I first saw it - and that wiki article links to the system requirements page at Microsoft. Hardly seems believable..

Comment: I've managed to install and run .net based applications in Windows 7 starter - one of which required download and (successful) install of .net 4(CP). So... it does all appear to work. So why do Microsoft say that it doesn't? Typo?